# Finding the probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X and Y are independent random variables that follow geometric distribution.

Then distribution of X given that X+Y=k is:

a) Binomial
b) Poisson
c) Uniform
d) None of these

**My attempt:**
I took both X and Y to have the same distribution, ie f(x) = f(y) = q^(x-1).p
then tried to proceed but nothing really came out of it...

Comment: Well? any ideas? Add your tries to the question.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are also identically distributed or only independent r.v?

Comment: Only independent... But I took them to be identically distributed trying to make it simpler.. but I just got  a weird expression...

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548525/how-to-compute-the-sum-of-random-variables-of-geometric-distribution

Comment: @M31 If they are identically distributed, you can use the relation $X+Y \sim NB(2, p).$ Now, try to expend $P(X=x|X+Y=k)$ using the definition $P(A| B) = P(A\cap B)/P(B), P(B)>0$.