# Probability geometric series summation

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

5. Suppose $ \sim (_1)$ on $\{1, 2, 3, \dots\}$, $ \sim (_2)$ on $\{1, 2, 3, \dots \}$, and  ⊥ . Let
   $ =  + $. Find $( = )$ under each condition.

a) Assume $ = _1 = _2$.

b) Assume $_1 \neq _2$. After setting up your summation, identify $, $ and $$ in a finite geometric series using the below formula and evaluate your summation.

$$ +  + ⋯ + ^{(−1)} = \frac{(1 − ^)}{ 1 - r}$$

EDIT: So part a) so far I know I should use negative binomial distribution for part a (# of trials until 2 successes). So I could use the formula $\binom{x-1}{r-1}\cdot  p ^ r \cdot (1 - p)^{(x - r)}$ with $r = 2$. But I don't know how to continue from that.

Comment: you need to show attempts of solution. people will not / shall not do your homework for you, but rather help with the experienced difficulties

Comment: I updated my thought process so far.

Comment: please use latex notation when posting; I will edit your question now, but you should do it in the future

Comment: and again, you are not showing any steps, proceed to the implementation of the steps you are suggesting

Comment: @aaaaaaaa For a) see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578951/find-the-probability-function-of-x-1x-2-in-geometric-distribution?noredirect=1&lq=1) and for b) see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135032/two-independent-geometric-random-variables-proof-of-sum?noredirect=1&lq=1) .