# Is this a known probability distribution: $p(x;\theta) = \theta(1-\theta)^x$ for $x=0,1,2,...$

Tags: probability-distributions, expectation

I'm given a set of random variables where each $X_i$ has distribution:

$p(x_i;\theta) = \theta(1-\theta)^{x_i}$ for $x=0,1,2,...$

I need to compute the expectation $E(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)$.

Is the distribution of $X_i$ something known?

I cannot recognize as a well known distribution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Geometric distribution.

Comment: Great, thanks. I guess that is a very well known distribution simply out of my current knowledge and experience. Thanks for your comment!. I just checked out the wikipedia page for Geometrical distribution and matches perfectly when the support is $x=0,1,2,3,...$ as in my case. Thanks again. Now just need to figure out the distribution of the summation of $n$ geometric random variables.

Comment: [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548525/how-to-compute-the-sum-of-random-variables-of-geometric-distribution)