# Describe the statistical model for the observed data ($T$)

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

A random sample of $6$ observations $(X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_6)$ is generated from a Geometric($\theta$), where $\theta \in (0, 1)$ unknown, but only $T = \sum_{i=1}^{6} X_i$ is observed by the statistician.

(a) Describe the statistical model for the observed data ($T$)

(b) (i) Is it possible to parameterize the model by $\Psi = \frac{1-\theta}{\theta}$ ? Prove your answer

(ii) Is it possible to parameterize the model by $\Psi = \theta(1-\theta)$ ? Prove your answer

Comment: Sum of i.i.d Geometric variables has a Negative binomial distribution. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548525/how-to-compute-the-sum-of-random-variables-of-geometric-distribution.

Comment: This post should NOT be reopened because it is [asked again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3086668), arguably with improved content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch out! The fact that $X_i \sim Geo(\theta)$ by no means implies that the sum of i.i.d. geometric random variables (i.e. $T$) has a geometric distribution!

Recall that the terminology *random sample* implies that the observations have the distribution that you have mentioned and are also conditionally independent.

Recall also the definition of statistical model for random samples.

Considering the random sample $\mathbf{X}_n=\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$, let $\mathcal{X}$ be the sample space for one of the random variables and $\Theta$ the parameter space. Any statistical model for random samples has the following form

$$\left\{\mathcal{X^n} \quad; \quad f_n(\mathbf{x}_n;\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n f_{X}(x_i;\theta) \quad ; \quad \theta\in\Theta\right\}$$

where $f_X$ is the probability law of one of the random variables in the random sample and $f_n$ is the joint probability of the random vector $\mathbf{X}_n$. That is, a triplet consisting of a sample space (for the random vector $\mathbf{X}_n$), a joint parametric probability distribution and a parameter space on which the family of distributions is parametrized.

So, steps to solve your problem:

1) Identify the correct sample space for your random variable $T$.

2) Determine the joint distribution of $\mathbf{X}_n$ by considering the independence and identical distribution of the random variables $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_6$.

3) Consider that $T$ is simply a *statistic* of the random sample, and so, from your statistical model for the random vector, you can easily find the statistical model for a function of the random vector. Just remember what you are looking for. A sample space (recall that $T: \mathcal{X}^n\rightarrow \mathcal{T}$, with $\mathcal{T}$ being the space in which the statistic $T$ has values), a probability law (this time for the sum of random geometric variables) and a parameter space.