# Is it possible to parameterize the model by $\Psi = \frac{1-\theta}{\theta}$ ? Prove your answer

Tags: probability, statistics

A random sample of $6$ observations $(X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_6)$ is generated from a Geometric($\theta$), where $\theta \in (0, 1)$ unknown, but only $T = \sum_{i=1}^{6} X_i$ is observed by the statistician.

(a) Describe the statistical model for the observed data ($T$)

(b)-(i) Is it possible to parameterize the model by $\Psi = \frac{1-\theta}{\theta}$ ? Prove your answer

(b)-(ii) Is it possible to parameterize the model by $\Psi = \theta(1-\theta)$ ? Prove your answer

---

**My attempt:**

(a) Since geometric is iid with Negative Binomial

Each $X_i$ ~ $\mathrm{Geometric}(\theta)$ therefore $T = \sum_{i=1}^{6}$ ~ $\mathrm{NegativeBinomial}(r, \theta)$ where $\theta \in (0, 1)$ unknown.

The probability function for T is given by $$f_{\theta}(t) = {t +r-1\choose t}(1-\theta)^t \theta^r$$ for $t = 0,1, \cdots, 6$

parameter is $\theta$ and parameter space is $[0,1]$

(b)-(i) and (b)-(ii) I'm not sure how to do. Would I just show they are one to one by graphing each of them? Not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer for (a) is a probability mass function so personally I would not use $f$ to describe it as that is often used for a density.  I would write $6$ rather than $r$.  And it depends on  whether your negative binomial starts at $0$ or $6$, i.e. whether your geometric distributions start at $0$ or $1$

For (b)(i)  you can say that $\Psi = \frac{1-\theta}{\theta} \iff \theta = \frac{1}{\Psi+1}$ at least if $\theta \not = 0$ which it has to be for the question to be sensible, so you can just use this as a substitution to parameterize the model by $\Psi$

For (b)(ii)  you can say that $\Psi = \theta({1-\theta})$ is satisfied by $\theta = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1+4\Psi}}{2}$, and the $\pm$ is a warning sign; for example $\Psi=0.09$ could be produced by $\theta=0.1$ or $\theta=0.9$ which would give you different probabilities, so so you cannot parameterize the model by this $\Psi$

Comment: "And it depends on whether your negative binomial starts at 0 or 6, i.e. whether your geometric distributions start at 0 or 1". What do you mean? Confuse at this part get the rest though

Comment: A negative binomial distribution may count the number of failures before the $n$th success (minimum possible value is $0$) or the number of attempts when then $n$th success occurs (minimum possible value is $n$).  When $n=1$ you have a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with a minimum possible value of $0$ or $1$ depending on which definition you are using; your question does not say.