# Expectation value of the reciprocal of a sum of geometrical

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

I was studying statistical inference when I had a problem with the following probability problem.

### Problem:

Suppose I have that $X_i \sim Geom(p)$ where $ p \in [0,1]$.

Let us define $Y= \frac{1}{\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} Xi}$.

I would like to find the value of $\mathbb{E}[Y]$.

### My attempt:

I tried using some manipulation and using the Beta function but I cannot solve anything.
I tried computing explicitly the sum involved but it is not easy.
I used [How to compute the sum of random variables of geometric distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548525/how-to-compute-the-sum-of-random-variables-of-geometric-distribution) to compute the distribution of the sum of Geometrical a.v.

Comment: There is a positive probability that the sum of the $X_i$ equals $0$.

Comment: Do you want the mean *conditional* on the sum of the $X_i$ being greater than $0$?